# Is there any subset of Complex numbers that is algebraically closed?

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory

That any polynomial that is allowed to have coefficients from that subset has also a root in that subset

Comment: The set of algebraic numbers. Many others.

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ and $\{0\}$ come to mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set of **algebraic numbers** is algebraically closed. It is countably infinite, so it is a very small subset of the set of complex numbers.

Note that an algebraic number is a zero of a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients. The set of algebraic numbers is the smallest algebraically closed subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

There are many other proper subsets of the complex numbers that are algebraically closed.

Answer (score 2):

the algebraic numbers, say $Q_0$ are the algebraic closure of the rationals. if $\alpha_1$ is transcendental then set $Q_1$ to be the algebraic closure of $Q(\alpha_1)$. this can be continued quite far, modulo the availability of a choice function